# Setup LDAP client on RHEL 6.5

Tags: authentication, openldap

I am preparing for RHCSA exams and trying to setup LDAP client on my RHEL 6.5 box

I am connecting to the online testing LDAP server [Here](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/)

I don't understand the relationship among following 3 files, not sure if they all needed or not.

```
/etc/openldap/ldap.conf
/etc/pam_ldap.conf
/etc/nslcd.conf
```

Basically I just put same settings in all the files, with correct syntax. For example
here is my /etc/nslcd.conf

```
uid nslcd
gid ldap
uri ldap://ldap.forumsys.com/
base dc=example,dc=com
binddn cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
bindpw password
ssl no
```

I verified that there is connection from my local host to ldap.forumsys.com port 389 and when I tried `id euler` I see traffice between my pc and LDAP server but it just could not resolve user name from LDAP server.

Again I am not even sure this is the correct way of verifying it.

Any advice ?

Comment: Use `system-config-authentication`. I wouldn't mess with the files unless you need to do something unusual.

Comment: To use `system-config-authentication` I would have to install the whole XWindows system. Actually I did and it says `You must use ldaps or TLS`.

Comment: `system-config-authentication` has a text mode (ncurses).

Comment: Try `authconfig-tui`. It is a Red Hat tool to configure authentication methods. Text mode, ncurses.